# Hadoop - Hive 2 ParseException - cannot recognize input near 'over' '(' 'partition' in expression specification

Tags: hadoop, hive

since doing an upgrade to Hive 2 this line in my query is failing giving me `FAILED: ParseException line 41:50 cannot recognize input near 'over' '(' 'partition' in expression specification`

```
select tempTable.*, (tempTable.rowrank - 1)/(max(tempTable.tableRowRank)) over (partition by tempTable.column1) percent
```

This works fine in Hive Server 1

???????

Answer (score 1):

just had to solve a similar issue

```
select tempTable.*, (tempTable.rowrank - 1)/(max(tempTable.tableRowRank) over (partition by tempTable.column1))/*<===== Close here*/ as percent
```